# Is text-width tabular possible?

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx} 
\def\dotfill#1{\cleaders\hbox to #1{.}\hfill}
\newcommand\dotline[2][.5em]{\leavevmode\hbox to #2{\dotfill{#1}\hfil}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lcr}
\textbf{aaaaaaaaaaa:} & \parbox[t]{6 cm} {\textbf{bbbbbbbbbb}\\ cccccccccccccc} & \dotline{2.0cm}
\end{tabularx}
\vspace{0.5 cm}
\\ddd
  \begin{table}[ht!]
     \centering

     \begin{tabular}{p{4cm} p{9cm}}
        Text column 1 & long long long long long long long text that should break \\

      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

I want to make a table fit to line width I integrated two solutions in one example but you can see after compile 'ddd' text is far away from the beginning of tables. It means tables cannot fit. Why?

Comment: `tabularx` has to have at least one X column and you have lcr `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lcr}`

Comment: are you sure you want to redefine `\dotfill` in that way, it would break any package that uses the usual definition (a quick search suggests at least 45 packages in my texlive installation)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by David Carlisle, `tabularx` works fine provided you specify at least one `X` column, and take into account `\parindent` if it is non-zero. Also, it is preferable to set the table width to `\linewidth`, which not always will be equal to `\textwidth`.

Here is an example with the same alignments you specified, 3 X columns and vertical rules to visualise the overall widths of X columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\def\dotfill#1{\cleaders\hbox to #1{.}\hfill}
\newcommand\dotline[2][.5em]{\leavevmode\hbox to #2{\dotfill{#1}\hfil}}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\bigskip

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|>{\centering}X|>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X|}
\textbf{aaaaaaaaaaa:} & \parbox[t]{6 cm} {\textbf{bbbbbbbbbb}\\ cccccccccccccc} & \dotline{2.0cm}
\end{tabularx}
\vspace{0.5 cm}
\\ddd
  \begin{table}[ht!]
     \centering
     \begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}| p{9cm}|}
        Text column 1 & long long long long long long long text that should break \\

      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the last column should be `>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X|`.

Comment: @Zarko: That's right. I guess I was in a lazy mood when I typed the code. I'll fix it. Thanks!